# HTML Javascript converter program

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple HTML program that will allow the user to input a number or word, then if the `userInput` matches what I have defined, it changes that input to something else, then outputs the new value on the screen.

Also looking for a button to reset the program (at any time to start over)

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Value Converter</h1>

  <input type="text" id="userInput"=>Enter the Value</input>
  <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
  <script>
    function test() {
      var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

      //Need to add If, else if, else to change the value of userInput
      // for example, If xxxx value, set to yyyy, then output yyyy 

      document.write(userInput);
    }           
    // Need to add a "reset" to go back to restart the program

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Working better now with... but where does the reset go?  How do I format the output?  all noob questions yes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Value Converter</h1>

<input type="text" id="userInput"=>Enter the Value</input>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function test()
            {
   var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
   if(userInput == "xxxx") {
      userInput="yyyy";
   }
   else if(userInput == "yyyy") {
      userInput="zzzz";
   }
   else {
      userInput="Not Found";
   }
        document.write(userInput);  
            }

            // Need to add a "reset" to go back to restart the program

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write` / `writeln` is only useful upon pageload. Dont try to use it in an event.

Comment: Thank you! The converter is working with your ideas.  But the reset is not working, where does it go?  How can I format the output to be larger and in the middle of the screen with a reset button as well?

Comment: Remove the extra `=` from the input

Comment: What extra = ?  It should look for a match and if it finds it, change it to the new value?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the function to the following.

```
function test()
{
   var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
   if(userInput == "xxxx") {
      // I forgot the updating part here. 
      document.getElementById("otherIdToWriteOutput").innerHTML = "yyyy";
   }
}
```

You can also add the reset button. And remove the current text using

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ""; // remove the inner html.
```

Comment: -1 because `document.write` doesn't make sense in a function called after initial page output

Comment: @devnull69, missed that part. :) I have editted the post now. :) Makes sense?

Comment: @devnull69, any suggestions..:) Would love them.

Comment: Where does the reset code go? Its not working, and how do I format the output to be in the middle of the screen and h1, and have a reset button below it?

Comment: That's another question I guess. @user3798473,

Comment: More like `document.getElementById("otherIdToWriteOutput").innerHTML = userInput;`

Comment: @devnull69, that **was** the main part of the answer which I missed. really sorry for that.

Comment: God Damn these Stack Police Guys